# Finding the region where the solution of a PDE is uniquely determined

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am given the following PDE
$$yu_x + xu_y = 0,$$
with the initial condition $u(0, y) = \exp\{-y^2\}$.

I managed to find the solution using the method which involves characteristics. I got that the solution must be constant on $y^2 - x^2 = C$ and the solution is equal to
$$u(x, y) = \exp\{x^2 - y^2\}.$$

Now I would like to find the region where the solution is uniquely defined. First of all I thought that if we have the condition with $x = 0$, then the characteristics curves must be defined for such $x$. Thus, when $x = 0$ we get
$$y^2 = C \implies C \ge 0,$$
which implies that $y^2 - x^2 \ge 0$. Is my reasoning correct?

I would appreciate a more general explanation, because it is not clear for me.

Comment: How did you get a characteristic $y^{2} - x^{2} = C$? The characteristic relating $x$ and $y$ is given by $$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} = dy \implies \text{arcsin}(x) = y + C_{1}$$

Comment: @mattos, of course you're right. I wrote the wrong PDE. Now it is correct. Sorry!